# Is there a name for this type of sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

There is an interesting sequence in problem $88$ of Chapter $12.1$ of Stewart's *PreCalculus*:

$$a_n=a_{n-a_{n-1}}+a_{n-a_{n-2}}$$

with $a_1=a_2=1$. It is defined recursively but contrary to most examples I know where $a_n$ is defined using the $r$ previous terms $a_{n-1}$, $\dots$, $a_{n-r}$ previous terms ($r$ fixed), here the terms used to defined $a_n$ varies. It was hard to believe at first that the sequence is well-defined.

**Is there a name for this kind of sequence?**

Comment: It is called "Hofstadter Q-sequence" in  https://oeis.org/A005185 and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter_sequence

Comment: OK, thanks. I didn't think about looking the OEIS. Can you add it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the [Hofstadter Q sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter_sequence#Hofstadter_Q_sequence), one of the Hofstadter sequences described by Douglas Richard Hofstadter in his book “Gödel, Escher, Bach.” These are described by non-linear recurrence relations.

The Hofstadter Q sequence is also listed as [A005185](https://oeis.org/A005185) in On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences®.

According to the Wikipedia article, it is unknown if the sequence is well-defined for all $n$.